# What does elementary function arithmetic without the induction axiom tell us about the exponential function?

Tags: exponentiation, axioms, peano-axioms, natural-numbers

We can extend Robinson arithmetic (Q) to include exponentiation, using the axioms

> 1) $x^0=1$ and 2) $x^{S(n)} = x^n*x$. [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function_arithmetic#Definition)

How much can this extension actually say about exponentiation? Because Robinson arithmetic is not associative or commutative, it doesn't seem like proving $x^{a+b} = x^ax^b$ or $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ are possible, both of which seem pretty fundamental when it comes to the exponential function.

In fact, I don't even think that proving $x^1 = x$ is possible:

$x^1 = x^{S(0)}*x = 1*x$, but Robinson arithmetic only proves that $x*1 = x$, not that $1*x = x$. I suppose this could be fixed by altering axiom 2), but that still wouldn't solve the other problems.

**I know that Q is weak, but these extra two axioms seem so weak and so bad at capturing exponentiation that it just doesn't even seem worth discussing. Am I missing something?**

Comment: This question deserves more discussion.  In particular, what is interpretable in Q + exponentiation?  There is a massive literature on what is interpretable in Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of EFA is missing a crucial component. EFA consists of $Q$, the axioms for exponentiation, **and induction for formulas with bounded quantifiers**. By contrast, $Q$ contains no induction at all, and $PA$ consists of $Q$ together with *full* induction.

As soon as we add induction to $Q$ - even a small amount of induction, like induction for bounded-quantifier formulas - we get a much more powerful system. In particular, the basic arithmetic facts which $Q$ curiously *can't* prove tend to be provable from bounded-quantifier induction. It's also worth noting that bounded-quantifier induction *in the language including exponentiation* is stronger than bounded-quantifier induction in the language of $Q$ alone; that is, EFA is not conservative over the theory $Q$ + induction for bounded-quantifier formulas in the language of $Q$.

---

For example, here's how to show that $1*x=x$ using bounded-quantifier induction:

*There's a slight language-mismatch here. EFA as described has a symbol "$1$" not present in the language of $Q$, and does not contain the symbol "$S$" which is present in the language of $Q$. So the description in the wiki page is a little bit inexact. But we can always replace "$1$" with "$S(0)$" and replace "$S(x)$" with "$1+x$," so we might as well assume we have both $1$ and $S$ to work with.*

- We have $x*0=0$ as an axiom in $Q$, so in particular we have $1*0=0$.
- Now suppose $1*x=x$. Then $1*(S(x))=(1*x)+1=x+1=S(x).$ *Note that "$x+1=S(x)$" really is the right thing to say here: treating "$1$" as an abbreviation for "$S(0)$," the statement "$x+S(0)=S(x)$" is provable in $Q$.*
- The formula $\varphi(x)\equiv$ "$1*x=x$" is a bounded-quantifier formula, so applying bounded-quantifier induction to the above two bullets we get $\forall x\varphi(x)$, and we're done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason I left out induction was because I was trying to make the set of axioms as minimal as possible while still including exponentiation. I definitely realize that EFA with induction can prove a lot of desirable things, but I’d like to see how much I can do without induction. Would you say that Q plus my two axioms about exponentiation has any value despite it not have very much power to prove things?

Comment: @Alex Ah, I'm sorry - based on the title, I thought you thought the system you were describing was EFA, and you were confused about why it was claimed to have nontrivial strength (e.g. by Friedman). If you like, I'll delete this answer, but you should fix the title since dropping induction gives you something other than EFA. As far as your question goes, I don't know (what do you mean by "value?") but my general feeling is negative.